# Java3D off-screen rendering memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, rendering, java-3d, off-screen

To enable saving of a snapshot of my 3d canvas, I've extended `Canvas3D` in the next way:

```
class OffScreenCanvas3D extends Canvas3D {
    OffScreenCanvas3D(GraphicsConfiguration graphicsConfiguration, boolean offScreen) {
        super(graphicsConfiguration, offScreen);
    }

    public BufferedImage doRender(int width, int height) {      
        BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        ImageComponent2D buffer = new ImageComponent2D(ImageComponent.FORMAT_RGBA, bImage);
        setOffScreenBuffer(buffer);
        renderOffScreenBuffer();
        waitForOffScreenRendering();
        bImage = getOffScreenBuffer().getImage(); 
        setOffScreenBuffer(null);
        return bImage;
    }

    public void postSwap() {}
}
```

And I add it as a view to the universe. And a main strategy is described here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/3D/PrintCanvas3D.htm

The problem is in memory leak. My app started to crash and when I tried to profile, I've found out that an instance of `OffScreenCanvas3D`  occupies almost **50MB** and the most part of it comes from two `ArrayList`s. Smaller one contains instances of `javax.media.j3d.RenderMolecule` and a larger one contains instances of Object each containing `javax.media.j3d.RenderAtomListInfo` and `javax.media.j3d.RenderMolecule`.

Can anybody suggest me, what I'm doing wrong?

#### UPDATE

I want to clarify that even when `doRender` is not called at all (eg. applications is launched and no more actions are taken) the memory is still accumulating. Below I'll add images that will show the situation better.

First one is a memory graph of an idle running application.
[image: memory grap]

The second one is a pie chart of memory taken by objects. Here `(a)` is the memory allocated for an instance of `OffScreenCanvas3D`, `(b)` is the memory ocupied by all the other objects.
[image: memory pie chart]

Also below you can see that `dirtyDlistPerRinfoList` and `dirtyRenderMoleculeList` take most of the space. Anything with prefix *dirty* gives me a feeling of a bad code, I don't know why
[image]

#### UPDATE2

It seems that the problem is in the next parts:

1. Objects of `dirtyDlistPerRinfoList` are added in the `updateCanvasResource` method of the `RenderBin` class. This happens with all the canvas.
2. `dirtyDlistPerRinfoList` is cleared in `updateDirtyDisplayLists` method of the `RenderBin` class.
3. `updateDirtyDisplayLists` is called from `doWork` (a horrible 1300 lines method) in class `Renderer` for every Canvas3D that's being rendered.

A thing is that offScreen canvas is not being rendered all the time, but just in the moment when the image is going to be saved. And yes, after saving the image, all the memory accumulated in `dirtyDlistPerRinfoList` is freed.

So the main question is next:

> Data of `dirtyDlistPerRinfoList` is continuously added to canvas that's not being rendered and so the memory won't be deleted. Is this my fault of Java3D bug?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @SaeidNourian no I didn't manage to do that. I tried to debug Java 3D but it was hell because all the fields were package-private and all the code directly accesses them. I think that I ended up some how sticking to a single canvas, but it was long time ago

Comment: Thanks Uko, I actually managed to get it to work properly last night. My mistake was that I thought I could save memory by removing OffscreenCanvas3D after each use. It turned out that it's better at memory management if I leave OffscreenCanvas3D attached to the university permanently. Also your setOffScreenBuffer(null); code helped my case. It now has no memory leaks. Perhaps they fixed it in the new JOGL's version of Java3D.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. A Java 3D application requires a minimum of 25+ MB memory plus the memory needed to store your model(s) in RenderMolecule and RenderAtomListInfo classes. Please be aware that BufferedImages also consume a lot of memory depending on their size. Calling System.gc() from time to time might help. BufferedImages are not that easy to remove.

Comment: Yes, but it's not ok when instance of `OffScreenCanvas3D` takes **150MB** right? And the most of this data is accumulated in the arrays described above. Also as far as I know there is no relation to the `BufferedImage` in this problem

Comment: I thing that data I've added to the question clearly shows that the problem is not in the buffered image

Answer (score 1):

Your `OffScreenCanvas3D` is exactly once, after `doRender` is called, subject of the `Renderer.doWork` method. You can prove this by overriding `preRender()`. Add:

```
@Override
public void preRender() {
    System.out.println("OffScreenCanvas3D preRender !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}
```

The instance's dirty lists will be cleared afterwards (as you mentioned above) and re-used at the time of next snapshot.

Sometimes names might be misleading. Lists with the prefix "dirty" contain objects that force necessary updates for the next rendering loop.

Java 3D definitely creates a lot of redundant data to split your scene graph data from rendering data. Your benefit amongst others is that you are allowed to call (almost) any Java 3D API method on any user thread at any time. No need to encapsulate Java 3D code in `Runnable`s as it is required for Swing and JavaFX interaction or into other constructs.

Comment: So how a solution should look like? At the moment a 250MB of memory is generated in 10min. Should I add something that will erase this data every minute, or there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The JDK tool JConsole allows watching the memory usage of your application. You can perform the garbage collector (GC) and check if memory is freed.

Calling 'java.lang.System.gc()' in your program would have the same effect.

Java 3D applications don't per se have memory leaks. While writing this post the 4-Canvas3D sample program PropellerUniverse is running and is monitored by JConsole. Every few seconds the JRE starts garbage collection automatically. The heap memory usage is at 25 MB and the non-heap memory usage is at 34 MB. The program is now running for 25 minutes. http://www.interactivemesh.org/testspace/j3dmeetsswing.html#heavyweight

Comment: The problem is not it whiting an app in Java3D but in rendering and saving png image of the universe. The only solution I've found was by using off screen canvas, but because of the way java3d is coded, they accumulate tons of memory

Answer (score 0):

Try to eliminate every step until you arrive at an example that still exhibits the problem. Does the problem still occur when only doing the following?

```
// Moved this to be a field
BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
ImageComponent2D buffer = new ImageComponent2D(ImageComponent.FORMAT_RGBA, bImage);

OffScreenCanvas3D(GraphicsConfiguration graphicsConfiguration, boolean offScreen) {
    super(graphicsConfiguration, offScreen);
    // set this just once
    setOffScreenBuffer(buffer);
}

public BufferedImage doRender(int width, int height) {
    renderOffScreenBuffer();
    waitForOffScreenRendering();

    // not necessary, image does not change
    // bImage = getOffScreenBuffer().getImage(); 
    // why is this necessary?
    // setOffScreenBuffer(null);

    return bImage;
}
```

Comment: yes it is. Moreover the memory is still accumulated if `doRender` isn't called at all. So in the way it's made in my example, the `BufferedImage` isn't instantiated at all. I've updated a question with more of (hopefully) useful data